# Generate mipmaped MTLTextures from AVFoundation camera stream

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avfoundation, metal

I'm using AVFoundation to get camera stream.
I'm using this code to get MTLTextures from:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

  id<MTLTexture> texture = nil;

  {
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

    MTLPixelFormat pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;

    CVMetalTextureRef metalTextureRef = NULL;

    CVReturn status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(NULL, _textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, pixelFormat, width, height, 0, &metalTextureRef);
    if(status == kCVReturnSuccess)
    {
     texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(metalTextureRef);

     if (self.delegate){

        [self.delegate textureUpdated:texture];
      }
      CFRelease(metalTextureRef);
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine, except for that generated **MTLTexture** object is not mipmaped (has only one mip level).
In this call:

```
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(NULL, _textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, pixelFormat, width, height, 0, &metalTextureRef);
```

There is a third parameter called "***textureAtributes***", I think it's possible to specify that I want mipmaped texture, but I haven't found any word in documentation what exactly goes there. Neither had I find a source code in which something else is passed instead of NULL.

In **OpenGLES** for **iOS** there is similar method, with same parameter, and also no words in documentation   .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just received an answer from Metal engineer [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1071205#1071205). Here's a quote:

> No, it is not possible to generate a mipmapped texture from a
>   CVPixelBuffer directly.
>   ***CVPixelBuffer*** images typically have a linear/stride layout, as non-GPU hardware blocks might be interacting with those, and most GPU
>   hardware only supports mipmapping from tiled textures.  You'll need to
>   issue a blit to copy from the linear ***MTLTexture*** to a private
>   ***MTLTexture*** of your own creation, then generate mipmaps.

As for ***textureAttributes***, there is only one key supported: `kCVMetalTextureCacheMaximumTextureAgeKey`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a method to get a mipmapped texture directly, but you can generate one yourself easily enough.

First use your Metal device to create an empty Metal texture that is the same size and format as your existing texture, but has a full mipmap chain. [See newTexture documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLDevice_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLDevice/newTextureWithDescriptor:)

Use your MTLCommandBuffer object to create a blitEncoder object. [See blitCommandEncoder documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLCommandBuffer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLCommandBuffer/blitCommandEncoder)

Use the blitEncoder to copy from your camera texture to your empty texture. destinationLevel should be zero as you are only copying the top level mipmap. [See copyFromTexture documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLBlitCommandEncoder_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLBlitCommandEncoder/copyFromTexture:sourceSlice:sourceLevel:sourceOrigin:sourceSize:toTexture:destinationSlice:destinationLevel:destinationOrigin:)

Finally use the blitEncoder to generate all the mip levels by calling generateMipmapsForTexture. [See generateMipMapsForTexture documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLBlitCommandEncoder_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLBlitCommandEncoder/generateMipmapsForTexture:)

At the end of this you have a metal texture from the camera with a full mip chain.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing right now. But I have frame drop doing this. I still think that it's possible in some other way. That "textureAtributes" might be able to do that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think this method must exist? Camera images typically do not require mipmaps, and when they do they still have to be generated (so doing the same kind of work as you are already doing). And if the documentation has no mention of it then it seems very unlikely it exists. If using the BlitEncoder to generate the mip maps is too slow, I'd consider trying to generate them via standard GPU rendering. This kind of operation is not so intensive that you should expect to be dropping frames.

Comment: You were right about that, so I give you bounty. But will accept mine answer because it is Apple proven.